# How to select RAND() between 1-n

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'd like to use `RAND()` in a query to be able to do the following:

`ODER BY id DESC` and allow `RAND()` to choose between last 3 inserted rows in the table. On the front-end when page is refreshed function rand will choose between 5 - 8 (on the table example) and show any data between those numbers.

### Query Example

```
function rand()
{
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT rows FROM table ORDER BY id LIMIT 1");
    $sth->execute();

}
```

### Table Example

```
+--------------+
| id |   name  |
+--------------+
|  1 |    Jon  |
|  2 |  Sarah  |
|  3 | Stevie  |
|  4 |   Stew  |
|  5 |   Dave  |
|  6 |    Kar  |
|  7 |  Stevo  |
|  8 |  Blake  |
+----+---------+
```

---

### EDIT

+----+
| id |
+----+
|    |
|    |
|    |
|    |
|    |
|    |
|    |
|    ||    |

Comment: `WHERE id=id` is supposed to mean what?

Comment: Nothing specifically!

Comment: @nathanhayfield because the results won't ever be the same, I used the table above as an example. The real table will have information updated daily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you need this:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM
  (SELECT id, name FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3) s
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
SELECT name
FROM users
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 3
```

http://davidwalsh.name/mysql-random

Comment: Thank you for your response, but that would not work as I'm trying to use RAND() to retrieve between 3 results and must be LIMITED by 1.

Comment: can you explain it a bit more